# Express Routing

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to route different url requests to different directories.  Right now, I am using this:

```
app.use(express.static(root));
```

to route everything to a particular directory within my project.  What I need to be able to do is conditionally route to that directory ONLY IF the request isn't for a subset of other directories.  Example:

```
if(route == '/blah1'){
    //route to particular folder
}
else if(route == '/blah2'){
    //route to a different folder
}
else{
    //otherwise use static route
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'mount' the static middleware at different points in the hierarchy. Place the default 'catch-all' directory at the end:

```
app.use('/blah1', express.static('/somedir1'));
app.use('/blah2', express.static('/somedir2'));
app.use(express.static('/defaultdir'));
```

See [the express.js documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: This is exactly the same conclusion I came to a couple of minutes ago.  Thanks!